# Reverse for 'edituser' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: django

I have this function in Django

```
function editFunc(id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{% url 'edituser' id %}",
                data: {
                    id: id
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(res) {
                    $('#ProductModal').html("Modifica dati");
                    $('#product-modal').modal('show');
                    $('#id').val(res.id);
                    $('#username').val(res.username);
                    $('#first_name').val(res.first_name);
                    $('#last_name').val(res.last_name);
                    $('#email').val(res.email);
                    $('#is_staff').val(res.is_staff);
                    $('#password').val("");
                    $("#password").attr("required", false);
                    $("#passl").html('Password (lasciare il campo in bianco per non modificare la password).');
                }
            });
        }
```

I checked the value of id and is ok
But i have the error: Reverse for 'edituser' with arguments '('',)' not found

To better explain:

```
id="1";
url: "{% url 'edituser' id %}",     doesn't work
url: "{% url 'edituser' "1" %}",    works
```

What is wrong and howto solve ?

Comment: `id` is a javascript variable and
 `{% url 'edituser' id %} ` is a template tag that is processed by the backend (django), so `id` is not available there.  

What you can do is send the URL in `editFunc` or pass `id` in Django context.

Comment: can you make an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

`url: "/edituser/" + id,`

Answer (score 0):

`id` is a javascript variable and `{% url 'edituser' id %}` is a template tag that is processed by the backend (django), so `id` is not available there.

What you can do is send the URL in `editFunc`

For example:
If your view is list_view then

```html
{% for object in object_list %}
<div>
...Display details
<button onClick="editFunc('{% url 'edituser' object.id %}', {{object.id}})">Edit</button>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Now update your function like this

```js
function editFunc(url, id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: {
                    id: id
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(res) {
                    $('#ProductModal').html("Modifica dati");
                    $('#product-modal').modal('show');
                    $('#id').val(res.id);
                    $('#username').val(res.username);
                    $('#first_name').val(res.first_name);
                    $('#last_name').val(res.last_name);
                    $('#email').val(res.email);
                    $('#is_staff').val(res.is_staff);
                    $('#password').val("");
                    $("#password").attr("required", false);
                    $("#passl").html('Password (lasciare il campo in bianco per non modificare la password).');
                }
            });
        }
```